# Using Sequel with jsonapi-serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sequel, fastjsonapi

In a Rails api project I added this gem for returning json

```
gem 'jsonapi-serializer'
```

These are the models I have defined, all very basic stuff going on.

```
class UserSequel < Sequel::Model(:users)
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I generated a serializer class

```
class UserSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :text
end
```

---

Now to the question

```
# Using ActiveRecord model returns some json as expected
UserSerializer.new(User.first).serializable_hash.to_json
```

The following however...

```
# Using Sequel model
UserSerializer.new(UserSequel.first).serializable_hash.to_json
```

returns this error message

> **FastJsonapi::MandatoryField (id is a mandatory field in the
> jsonapi spec)**

I don't quite understand why this happens, because obviously the Sequel model contains a column `id` and calling this returns the expected outcome

```
UserSequel.first.id 
# => 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this was a bug in the `jsonapi-serializer` gem which has been resolved now. *(not released though as of this writing).*

Use the `git` option to get the latest version

```
gem 'jsonapi-serializer', git: 'git://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer'
```

https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer/issues/112